# trying to import a excel csv (?!) file with panda

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I am new to Python/Panda and I am trying to import the following file in Jupyter notebook via pd.read_

Initial file lines:
[image: Initial file lines]

either pd.read_excel or pd.read_csv returned an error.
eliminating the first row allowed me to read the file but all csv data were not separated.

Comment: It'd be great if you could post the actual first 10 lines of your file as a code block (open it in a text editor instead of excel/similar and copy paste that) and what the *exact* error is (you should get a traceback you can copy/paste here) rather than in an image... However, it does look like all your columns are crammed into one CSV like field in only the first column...

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. I was able to read the data, but, as Jon said:  "it does look like all columns are crammed into one CSV like field in only the first column" ... I

Comment: Is there a way to separate the data? I have used Charlie hint (pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',') but nothing changed... I have code lines, since I am just trying to read the file... Thx Max

Answer (score 0):

could you share the line of code you have used so far to import the data? 
Maybe try this one here:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',')
```

It is always easier for people to help you if you share the relevant code accompanied by the error you are getting.